# Mute Yarn has unmet peer dependency warning

Tags: yarnpkg

I know what peer dependencies are in package.json and the reason why the warning

> ....has unmet peer dependency ....

will appear, also I know that npm v7 will install them but currently I am using yarn and I don't want the peer dependencies to be installed (there are many of them and probably there will be a chance for conflicts).

Is there any way to silence these warnings? I know there is an option for `yarn install -silent` but it didn't work and I still have these warnings... in my case there are a lot of them.

Comment: you've hit the nail on the head. everywhere i see a question about unmet peer dependency warnings the recommended resolution is "install unmet peer dependencies"; but if everyone does that, what's the point of specifying them as peer dependencies in the first place? why not normal dependencies? unfortunately there seems to be no out-of-the-box way to suppress the warnings for peer dependencies i don't intend to install.